# Words to describe a person that values merit and achievemnt

Tags: adjectives, synonyms, antonyms

Or, you could say, a proponent of meritocracy (descriptors for *opponents* of meritocracy also welcome, see details below). Please don't say "meritocrat", I would rather avoid that one.

Nouns and adjectives are all welcome, single-word descriptions preferred, but two-word descriptions are fine too. The terms should also not rely on reference to other ideologies or political systems, like many thesauri seem to.

A bit of background:
I'm in the process of describing a list of personal values, assigning an adjective or noun to various levels of these values. The descriptions go both ways, that is the range should describe anything from people to whom this value is extremely (quite possibly too) important to people who are actively opposed to it.

As an example, one of them is "Individuality", for which I came up with the following range, from lowest to highest:
`doctrinal, conformist, conventionalist, individualist, egocentric, narcissist`

One of the values on that list is merit, i.e. how much a person believes how important personal achievements should be for societal progress. And... I can't find any meaningful descriptors for such a mindset, and the thesauri seem to be somewhat empty in that regard. I would appreciate any help.

As an interesting side note, I had much less trouble finding descriptors for people that value social status, as in proponents of Aristocracy. I guess the idea of a meritocracy hasn't been around in our culture for too long...

Comment: Morality, goodness, rightness, correctness - a character proper behaviour.

Comment: Those assume that meritocracy is already considered good and moral... I'm looking for terms that do not reference a predefined moral framweork. Like, for example, if I'd describe a person that highly values wealth as "greedy", that has connotations in the moral framework, but it doesn't rely on the moral framework for its primary meaning. It would still communicate this core meaning even if e.g. a Ferengi said it, it would just bear different moral connotations. It's words like that I'm looking for.

Comment: Difficult, because "merit" just seems to mean deserving of praise. How do you measure merit? Is it by academic qualifications? That seems too narrow. Merit might simply be a superset of some of the other values?

Comment: Well, I guess in this context it could be replaced with "competence" - how much somebody values skill. That doesn't seem to solve the problem, however

Comment: [Found 'reputationism' on Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reputationism), except there is no linked page or definition to its related term 'reputationist'.

Comment: Huh... not very established it seems, but the most solid term I've seen so far. Thanks!

Comment: @UncleBob Yes, it only appears to be mentioned on Wiktionary...

Comment: Can you give us an idea of the entries you will put *under* the heading you are looking for?  If we had something like the doctrinal-narcissist spectrum to work with, we might have a better shot at giving the category a name.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "important for societal progress".  For the individual's progress in society or for  society's progress as a whole?

Comment: @remarkl:  I'm not looking for the heading. THe heading is "merit", or "competence" if you will. THe terms to put under it are the ones I'm desperately trying to come up with.

Comment: @TRomano: Indeed. progress in society is what I meant. I.e. a descriptor for a person that thinks that an individuals progress in society should mainly depend on their competence.

Comment: @UncleBob So you are looking for several words that relate to how one values merit, from least to most? E.g., nepotistic at one end to monomaniacally meritocratic at the other? I think you'll have trouble trying to create gradations using words rather than numbers, as the named deviations from pure meritocracy are not quantitative. There are categories of deviation - sexism, racism, experience, friendship, etc. - but any or all of these could co-exist.  The thing calls for a 1-10 scale.  (Not trying to tell you how to do your business, just saying how unsuited language is to the task.)

Comment: @remarkl: It's funny, I just came up with nepotism a few minutes ago :) went with partisan instead, since it'sless specific (the coexistance problem you mention). Also funny thing, I started out with numbers, but then I found that the documentation required several descriptors so people understood what was meant, so I decided to go with a scale from 0 to 5 and add a descriptor to every value to avoid having people looking up the documentation all the time... In other words, all the things you say are true, but I found it to be impractical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fitting with your theme:

- “Egalitarian” describes the person personifying meritocracy. “Elitist” would be an antonym.
- Other words that pop up along this path are “democratic” and “dictatorial”
- “Appointed” and “elected” may also apply.

Comment: I thought about egalitarian, but had some issues with it because while it is accurate if for egalitarians that advocate equality of opportunity it fits, but egalitarians advocating equality of outcome are not meritocratic at all... In any case, I have thought a lot about this and concluded that there's simply no words describing what I want accurately, so I'm currently restructuring my values list into something more generic with less overlap.